# Need to get the error message from the Controller to Display reply OK and there is an error

Tags: visualforce, javascript, controller

this is now working fine but the problem in this it not recognizing the errorMessage attribute from the controller.

1. I need the confirmation page - working now
2. if the user press OK and there is a validation rule error it should be thrown to my javascript - NOT WORKING no error shown
3. if no error the function should be kick in reload the sreen - working now.

**VF page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="CreateCaseController" >
    <apex:form id="caseform" >
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!Renewal}" name="createNewCase" reRender="" oncomplete="testSFDC()">
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <!-- reRender="caseform" -->
    </apex:form>
    <script>
       theQueryString = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}';
       var getInput =confirm('Are you sure?');
       console.log(getInput);
    if(getInput==true)
    {
      createNewCase();
       *if ('{!errorMessage}' != ''){
    {
     alert('An issue has been encountered while submitting the order. Please correct the following problem and try again: \n' +
     '{!errorMessage}');
    }
    }*
    else
    {
      theQueryString = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}';
      document.location = '/' + theQueryString;
    }

    function testSFDC()
    {
      window.location.href='/' + theQueryString ;
    }
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
  private PageReference handleRenewalRequest(RecordType recordType, Id OwnerId, integer btn){
        String theId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppid');
        System.Debug('parameter= ' + theId);
        if (theId == null) {
            theId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        }
        if (theId == null)
            return null;

        List<Case> listCase = new List<Case>();
        List<Opportunity> listOpp = new List<Opportunity>();

        for (Opportunity o : [select id, Renewal_Invoice_ROPP__c, Special_Instructions__c, name, AccountId from Opportunity where id = :theId]) {

            String theDescription = o.Special_Instructions__c;
            if (theDescription == null) {
                theDescription = 'N/A';
            }

            if (btn == 1){
                o.type = 'Auto Renewal';}
                else
            {o.type = 'Manual Renewal';}
            o.Renewal_Stage__c = 'Pending Renewal';
            o.Processing_Status_ROPP__c = 'Completed';
            listOpp.add(o);

            listCase.add(new Case(  Opportunity__c          = o.id,
                                    AccountId               = o.AccountId,
                                    Subject                 = 'Renewal Request - ' + o.name, Description = theDescription,
                                    Type                    = 'Renewal Processes',
                                    Status                  = 'New',
                                    Type_Sub_Category__c    = 'Request to Renew',
                                    RecordTypeId            = recordType.Id,
                                    OwnerId                 = OwnerId));
        }

        try {

            if (listOpp.size() > 0)
                update listOpp;

            if (listCase.size() > 0 &&  btn == 2)
                insert listCase;

        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            string message = ex.getMessage();
            string errorMes = 'FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION';
            if (message.contains(errorMes)){
                message = message.substring(message.indexOf(errorMes) + errorMes.length() + 2);
            }
            errorMessage = message;
        }

       return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your errorMessage property in controller.It should be something like this:

```
public String errorMessage {get;set;}
```

In controller constructor , you can define your errorMessage maybe something like this.

```
errorMessage ='NO_ERROR';
```

In javascript ,assign errorMessage with javascript variable :

```
var errorMsg = '{!errorMessage}';
```

Compare it something like this :

```
if(errorMsg != 'NO_ERROR')
```

Also try to print out errorMessage by using console.log or alert just to check what actual value from controller.

Hopefully this will help.